# Is there a good way of coloring tf.logging (tensorflow terminal printing)?

Tags: python, logging, tensorflow

I am an intense Tensorflow user. So far, when I need to print something, I used to use the `logging` library with `coloredlogs`. These are very useful, and I could see what is going on more easily:

```
import logging
import coloredlogs
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
coloredlogs.install(level='DEBUG', logger=logger, ...)
logger.debug("-- preparing network..")   <-- eg, debug in green, info in cyan, ...
```

However, Tensorflow actually provides built-in `tf.logging`. For compatibility, I decided to use it. In this case, is there a way that I can assign some colors to `tf.logging.{debug, info, warning, ...}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module coloredlogs works for Tenosorflow in-built logging too.

```
from tensorflow import logging
coloredlogs.install(level='DEBUG')
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.DEBUG)
```

I tried this. Working perfectly.
But you should set both logging verbosity to same. Or coloredlogs log verbosity should be higher.

Comment: Thanks! However, when I tried `logging.debug('aa')`, it prints duplicated messages such as `DEBUG:tensorflow:aa` (not in color) and  `2018-04-16 02:01:41 hostname tensorflow[4685] DEBUG aa` (in color). Is there a way I can keep only the latter?

Comment: It happens because coloredlogs uses pythons logging framework. So You are actually using python's and tensorflows logging techniques.

Comment: Thank you so much. So, you mean there is no way to print only one of them (only tensorflow's)? I am fine with that, but I am so curious.